# Adding Cart Indicator and Need to Check if it's Empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not very familiar with PHP, but I managed to get the cart indicator working on my website so it updates the cart totals in real time vs requiring a page refresh (Yay! Small wins).

I am currently trying to expand on this but coming up short on answers. What I am looking to do is check if the cart total indicator is "0" and if it is, I simply want to hide the totals div, or add a class to it where I can hide it there.

Here's what I have so far, any help is appreciated!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'iconic_cart_count_fragments', 10, 1 );
function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {

    $fragments['.fa-shopping-cart'] = '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" class="header-cart-count">' . "<span class='cart-indicator'>" . WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</span>'. '</i>';
    return $fragments; 

    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    if ( $cart_count !== 0 ) {
    // Here's where I want to Hide .cart-indicator
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `return $fragments;` as the function will never get past that and check if the `$cart_count` is equal to 0 (currently you have it set to NOT equal).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'iconic_cart_count_fragments', 10, 1 );
function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {

    $fragments['.fa-shopping-cart'] = '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" class="header-cart-count">' . "<span class='cart-indicator'>" . WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</span>'. '</i>';


    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    if ( $cart_count === 0 ) {
    // Here's where I want to Hide .cart-indicator
      $fragments['.fa-shopping-cart']  = WHATEVER YOU WANT TO OUTPUT HERE
    }

    return $fragments;
}
```

Essentially, this sets up the `$fragments` var, but IF the `$cart_count` is equal to 0, then `$fragements` will be updated accordingly.